# Cloned element change events behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a the follow problem:

I have a field that listens to changes that happen in a field, but when that object is cloned, them it overrides one field to another, I mean if in one field I choose **3**, it displays **3**, but if i choose **4** in the cloned field, them it displaya **4** instead of **7**, why?
I know I have made a shallowcopy(plainObject) but at the end it should be as easy as:

```js
parseInt($('.selector')[0].value) + parseInt($('.selector')[1].value)
```

Whereever there are more than 1 element.

I have prepared a ***fiddle***: [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Qiqke/o3Lv05k4/)

I have never faced to cloned object, I have read that making `clone(true,true)` will make a deep-cloning with events and a lot of but there was no lucky, any suggest or idea??

```js
$(document).on("click", "#btnNewDistribution", function() {
  var distributionContainers = $("#DistributionContainers");
  var lastDistributionContainer = $(distributionContainers).children().last(".DistributionContainer");
  var newDistributionContainer = $(lastDistributionContainer).clone(true);
  $(newDistributionContainer).find(".ChildAgesContainer").empty();
  distributionContainers.append(newDistributionContainer);
});
$('.AmountField').on('change', function() {
  document.getElementById("habitacionesFiltroTop").innerHTML = this.value;
  calculoAmount();
});
calculoAmount = function() {
  for (var i = $('.well').length - 1; i == 0; i--) {
    if ((i - 1) > 0) {
      habitacionesFiltroTop.html(parseInt($('.form-control.AmountField')[i].value) + parseInt($('.form-control.AmountField')[i - 1].value));
    } else {
      habitacionesFiltroTop.html(parseInt($('.form-control.AmountField')[i].value));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https:////code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<fieldset id="DistributionContainers">
  <legend>Distribuciones</legend>
  <section class="col col-md-3 DistributionContainer">
    <div class="well">
      <div class="form-group">
        <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right btnDeleteDistribution" href="#" title="Quitar distribucion"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-6">Habitaciones</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <select class="formControl AmountField" type="number" min="1" max="5"><br><br>
            <option value=1>1</option>
            <option value=2>2</option>
            <option value=3>3</option>
            <option value=4>4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-6">Adultos</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <select class="form-control AdultsField" type="number" defaultValue=2 min="1" max="10"><br><br>
            <option value=1>1</option>
            <option value=2>2</option>
            <option value=3>3</option>
            <option value=4>4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-6">Niños</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input class="form-control ChildsField" type="number" defaultValue=0 min="0" max="6"><br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group ChildAgesContainer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</fieldset>


<section class="col col-md-1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnNewDistribution" href="#" title="Añadir distribución"><i class="fa fa-plus"> Add new Distri</i></a>

  </div>
</section>



<!--WHERE I WANNA PLACE THE RESULT OF SUM-->
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
  Habitaciones:
  <output id="habitacionesFiltroTop">
    </output>
</div>
```

> Thank you very much!!

Comment: Please fix the console errors in the snippet I made you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because your logic to sum the values of all the `.AmoutField` elements is flawed. Firstly `habitacionesFiltroTop` is an Element object, not a jQuery object, so `html()` won't work. Secondly you can use `each()` to loop over *all* `.AmountField` elements. Try this:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#btnNewDistribution", function() {
  var $distributionContainers = $("#DistributionContainers");
  var $lastDistributionContainer = $distributionContainers.children().last(".DistributionContainer");
  var $newDistributionContainer = $lastDistributionContainer.clone(true);

  $newDistributionContainer.find(".ChildAgesContainer").empty();
  $distributionContainers.append($newDistributionContainer);
});

$('.AmountField').on('change', function() {
  var totalHabitaciones = 0;
  $('.AmountField').each((i, el) => totalHabitaciones += parseInt(el.value, 10) || 0);
  $('#habitacionesFiltroTop').text(totalHabitaciones);
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="DistributionContainers">
  <legend>Distribuciones</legend>
  <section class="col col-md-3 DistributionContainer">
    <div class="well">
      <div class="form-group">
        <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right btnDeleteDistribution" href="#" title="Quitar distribucion"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-6">Habitaciones</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <select class="formControl AmountField" type="number" min="1" max="5"><br><br>
            <option value=1>1</option>
            <option value=2>2</option>
            <option value=3>3</option>
            <option value=4>4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-6">Adultos</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <select class="form-control AdultsField" type="number" defaultValue=2 min="1" max="10"><br><br>
            <option value=1>1</option>
            <option value=2>2</option>
            <option value=3>3</option>
            <option value=4>4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-6">Niños</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input class="form-control ChildsField" type="number" defaultValue=0 min="0" max="6"><br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group ChildAgesContainer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</fieldset>


<section class="col col-md-1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnNewDistribution" href="#" title="Añadir distribución"><i class="fa fa-plus"> Add new Distri</i></a>

  </div>
</section>



<!--TOTAL HABITACIONES-->
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
  Habitaciones:
  <output id="habitacionesFiltroTop">
   </output>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks not to much complicated, can I ask you why do you make an `.each(i, el)` , whats the meaning of the 2 params?

Comment: The `each()` is to loop over every `.AmountField` in the DOM. The function inside that call runs for every element found and adds it text to the running total. In the function the `i` is the index of the current element in the collection, and `el` is a reference to that element. For more information, see the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/each

Comment: Thank you @rory-maccrossan, I imagined that, I didnt play to much with the new functions like `each`, `filter`.. . But yes now its a little bit clear, for keeping a reference to what object we are iterating we need to make a key-value, its normal and nice, so thank you very much, Rory!!(again jeje).